# Custom expiration date for different objects using memcached and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, memcached

I'm using [this client](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot)  in my `Spring boot` project to connect to my `memcached` instance running on my cluster.

Everything works fine BUT so far I could only set on expiration date for all my caches, which is not convenient for me now, I want to able to set custom expiration dates like it's possible to do on `memcached` for `Appengine`.

Anybody has any idea? the client doesn't seem that flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You could set custom expiration per cache name also with [memcached-spring-boot](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot) library. You can just do it through `memcached.cache.expirations` configuration property. E.g.:

```
 memcached.cache:
     servers: example1.com:11211,example2.com:11211
     mode: static
     expirations: 86400, cache_name1:3600, cache_name2:108000
```

Here `86400` represents *global expiration* (used for all caches). And in case you want to have different expiration value per cache, you can set it up as `cache_name1:3600` (cache with name `cache_name1` will expire in `3600` seconds).

In this case your cache configuration is outside the source code, so it would be easier for you to configure different expiration per different environment (e.g. *dev*, *prod*).

Comment: Yeah I started using this library at the beginning but they didn't have this feature so I actually requested it and they did it few days back so I switched back :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because Spring does not have native support for custom expiration. I suggest you use [`simple-spring-memcached`](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached) with Spring Boot to enable custom expiration. If you use this library you have two options:

1. Use the annotations provided by `simple-spring-memcached`. They support custom expiration.
2. Use the `ExtendedSSMCacheManager` provided by `simple-spring-memcached` to integrate with Spring Boot's native caching. It allows you to set expiration as part of the cache name like so:

   ```
   @Cacheable("default#3600")   
   public ComplexSerializableResult compute(Long input) {
       // ...
       return result;   
   }
   ```

   Here `default` is the cache name and the expiration is set to 3600 seconds.

For more information on how to set up `simple-spring-memcached` with Spring Boot see the [SSM wiki](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached/wiki/Getting-Started) or MemCachier's [Spring Boot documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier#spring-boot).

For step by step instructions on how to use `simple-spring-memcached` with Spring Boot see this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-boot-memcache). It is created for the Heroku platform but works independently from Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I tried it yet the #3600 didn't actually work for me, the cache didn't expire

Comment: Are you sure you have `simple-spring-memcached` properly set up?

Comment: Before getting into that, do you know why I cannot cache without a key using this @ReadThroughSingleCache? if I don't annotate an arg with 
@ParameterValueKeyProvider i get No KeyProvider annotation found method but sometimes i don't have arguments to pass, so what can I do then?

Comment: You can use `@ReadThroughAssignCache`. It takes the parameter `assignedKey` so you can set the key explicitly. An example of this annotation is in the tutorial I linked in my answer.